# how to disable button and show input title

Tags: javascript

Hi all I have the following code:
[my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-beaver-02502)

```js
let companyNameField = document.getElementById('FormField_6_input');
let button = document.getElementById('ContinueButton_6');
companyNameField.addEventListener('input', validate);

function validate() {
  var companyNameValue = companyNameField.value;
  var companyRGEX = /[2-9]\d{3}/;

  if (companyNameValue.match(companyRGEX)) {
    button.disabled = false;

  } else {
    button.disabled = true;
    companyNameField.setAttribute("pattern", '[2-9]\\d{3}');
    companyNameField.setAttribute("title", "wrong");
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="" onchange="validate()">
  <input type="text" id="FormField_6_input" name="CompanyName" />
  <button id="ContinueButton_6">Continue</button>
</form>
```

With my function, I am checking if my input text satisfies my regex. If not then I disabled my button.

With disabling I also want to set the "title" attribute to my input for showing a message.

With console log I can see that pattern and title were successfully added to my input but when I am starting to write something wrong only my button gets disabled and the title not showing the error message.

How can I fix that?

Comment: sorry but your code example seems to work for me. When typing a word the button get's disabled and the title gget's set to "wrong". Maybe I didn't get your question right

Comment: A title is only shown when you hover over it with the mouse. So when you are typing you are not hovering over the input with the mouse. You need to move the mouse to see the updated title.

Comment: yes you are right , title is visible when I am hovering, but this is not user-friendly. How can I show that title without hovering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, title attribute could only be shown while the mouse is hovering on the tag, so it is not suitable to add title in input. Maybe it works in next code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" onchange="validate()">
        <input type="text" id="FormField_6_input" name="CompanyName" />
        <button id="ContinueButton_6">Continue</button>
        <span id="wrong_text" style="display:none">wrong</span>
    </form>

    <script>
        let companyNameField = document.getElementById('FormField_6_input');
        let button = document.getElementById('ContinueButton_6');
        let wrongText = document.getElementById('wrong_text');
        companyNameField.addEventListener('input', validate);

        function validate() {
            var companyNameValue = companyNameField.value;
            var companyRGEX = /[2-9]\d{3}/;

            if (companyNameValue.match(companyRGEX)) {
                button.disabled = false;
                wrongText.style.display = "inline";
            } else {
                button.disabled = true;
                companyNameField.setAttribute("pattern", '[2-9]\\d{3}');
                companyNameField.setAttribute("title", "wrong");
                wrongText.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the above snippet, I've tried to solve your issue. Let me know if it works

```js
    let companyNameField = document.getElementById("FormField_6_input");
    let button = document.getElementById("ContinueButton_6");
    companyNameField.addEventListener("input", validate);

    function validate() {
      var companyNameValue = companyNameField.value;
      var companyRGEX = /[2-9]\d{3}/;

      if (companyNameValue.match(companyRGEX)) {
        button.disabled = false;
      } else {
        button.disabled = true;
        companyNameField.setAttribute("pattern", "[2-9]\\d{3}");
        companyNameField.setAttribute("title", "wrong");
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="">
      <input
        type="text"
        id="FormField_6_input"
        name="CompanyName"
        onchange="validate()"
      />
      <button id="ContinueButton_6" disabled>Continue</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Need some clarifications about the title issue

Answer (score 0):

instead of using regex you can also use parseInt(); and isNaN(); to only allowing numbers to enter.